# Antlr4 Not following alternate path when second predicate fails

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

Here is my code:

```
@parser::members {

public boolean twoDigitDay(String text) {
    try {
        int day = Integer.parseInt(text);
        if (day >= 1 && day <= 31)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return false;
}
public boolean twoDigitMonth(String text) {
    try {
        int day = Integer.parseInt(text);
        if (day >= 1 && day <= 12)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

```
date        :   day seperator month
        |   month seperator day
        ;

day             :   dayTwoDigits ;
month           :   monthTwoDigit;
monthTwoDigit   :   {twoDigitMonth(getCurrentToken().getText())}? TWO_DIGITS;
dayTwoDigits    :   {twoDigitDay(getCurrentToken().getText())}? TWO_DIGITS;
seperator   :   ('/');
ONE_DIGIT   :   [0-9];
TWO_DIGIT   :   ONE_DIGIT ONE_DIGIT
```

Problem here is:
input - 12/29 (it should go to month seperator day path because first is failing). Parser is throwing No Viable Input at 29... Since 29 doesn't satisfy the month criteria which is define in @member . In this case 12 is passed according to date method (1-31) after that 29 is going to month check(1-12) and it fails. It should backtrack to the root and follow the second path rather than giving No Viable Input at 29 exception.

Answer (score 0):

Let's move semantics predicates directly to `date` grammar rule.

```antlr
TWO_DIGIT : [0-9][0-9];

date
    : {twoDigitDay(getCurrentToken().getText()) && twoDigitMonth(_input.LT(3).getText())}? 
        TWO_DIGIT '/' TWO_DIGIT # dayAndMonth
    | {twoDigitMonth(getCurrentToken().getText()) && twoDigitDay(_input.LT(3).getText())}?
        TWO_DIGIT '/' TWO_DIGIT # monthAndDay
    ;
```

When we start matching rule `date` we firstly check the `dayAndMonth` named alternative. We match `dayAndMonth` only if the first digits are proper day and the second digits are correct month (represent with `_input.LT(3)` token). Otherwise we will match `monthAndDay` named alternative.

Comment: Hi Quepas, This was just a code fragment of my Date grammar. there are lot of other cases which handles around 100 types of date. the solution you are proposing would probably be too complex to implement. My main concern here is in case of No Viable Alt Exception why don't ANTLR go to next rule and check? Is there any way I can forcefully ask Antlr4 to check for the next rule?

Comment: @Shiva Hi, for know I don't have any good solution. Maybe I will come up with something later :)